# QRadioButton: Setting all radio buttons in a group to unchecked state

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have three radio buttons, let's call them R1, R2 and R3. (R1 is in the checked set)

My problem is that I have a method called `check()` that gets the current radio button using:

```
def check(self):
    if R1.isChecked():
      # 
    if R2.isChecked():
      # 
    if R3.isChecked():
      #
```

Based on which radio button is active, the appropriate method is further called.

However the problem with this approach is that when the form loads up, R1 is checked. Then when I call the `check()`, since R1 is already checked when the form loads, it just returns R1 always.

What would be the way to fix this? I want that depending on the choice of the user, the appropriate method be called.

So I was wondering whether it is possible to have no radio button checked when the form loads up?

Comment: If none of the radio buttons are checked when the form loads, would that fix your problem?

Comment: QRadioButton is not checked by default and in order to check it when you create it you need to call `setChecked(True)`, so my guess is all you need to do is not to set any of the buttons checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hope this could help you, initially all the radio buttons will be in unchecked state.

```
     QGroupBox *groupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Exclusive Radio Buttons"));
     QRadioButton *radio1 = new QRadioButton(tr("&Radio button 1"));
     QObject::connect(radio1,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(clickkedstate(bool)));
     radio1->setAutoExclusive(false);
     QRadioButton *radio2 = new QRadioButton(tr("R&adio button 2"));
     QObject::connect(radio2,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(clickkedstate(bool)));
     radio2->setAutoExclusive(false);
     QRadioButton *radio3 = new QRadioButton(tr("Ra&dio button 3"));
     radio3->setAutoExclusive(false);
     QObject::connect(radio3,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(clickkedstate(bool)));

     radio1->setChecked(false);
     radio2->setChecked(false);
     radio3->setChecked(false);


     QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;
     vbox->addWidget(radio1);
     vbox->addWidget(radio2);
     vbox->addWidget(radio3);
     vbox->addStretch(1);
     groupBox->setLayout(vbox);
     setLayout(vbox);
```